# Is it possible to solve trignomatic problems using python?

Tags: python, math, trigonometry

I was thinking to create a app which simply the trignomatic problems using python with math lib, Is it possible to solve them without providing the value of angle?

Example:
Input:
(cosx + sinx)/(cosx - sinx)
Output:
(1 + tanx)/(1-tanx)

It will me a lot.

Comment: If it's a programming language, it can be used to solve trigonometric problems. However, what you're asking isn't so much solving trigonometric problems, but "doing symbolic maths", which is quite a step up, and (except for programming languages that are _dedicated_ to that task like MatLab or Mathematica) always requires a symbolic maths library. But on a maths note: that example doesn't equal either tan(2x) or tan²(x) =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is. You could use the `sympy` package. A possible implementation of your question would be:

```
from sympy import symbols, cos, sin, tan, simplify, trigsimp

# Define the variable
x = symbols('x')

# Define the expression
expr = (cos(x) + sin(x)) / (cos(x) - sin(x))

# Simplify the expression
simplified_expr = trigsimp(expr)

print(simplified_expr)
```

This outputs `tan(x + pi/4)`, which is equal to your solution.